# Error tipo "La conversión especificada no es válida."

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework, wpf, linq-to-sql

Os escribo este post para preguntaros sobre qué pasos he de seguir para solucionar el problema de tipo:
"La conversión especificada no es válida.". El error en cuestión me salta al hacer una consulta desde **C# EntityFramework** con **LINQ** a la base de datos de SQL; el ejemplo del código es este:

`Coches CocheEntity = Context.Coches.Inlcude(k=>k.Marcas).FirstOrDefault(k => k.ID = IdCoche);`.

He estado investigando un poco y al sumergirme en el código he descubierto que me salta en un campo de una relacion **IDTipoCoche**. He mirado que la BBDD y el modelo en el proyecto están igual con los mismos tipos de datos o su equivalente en C#.

Alguna posible respuesta? Muchas gracias de antemano!

Comment: Te recomiendo que modifiques tu pregunta agregando la definición de la clase cocheentity, además de la definición de la variable idcoche

Comment: @JuanSalvadorPortugal Gracias por el interés pero me acabo de dar cuenta de que el error estaba en la BBDD que se había cambiado el tipo identificador que se usaba antes (GUID) por un INT y en el modelo del proyecto no se habia notificado dicho cambio. Muchas gracias

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tras un rato investigando he descubierto que el error estaba en la propia BBDD que se había cambiado el ID de Marcas y se había cambiado solo en la BBDD y no en el modelo del proyecto. **Error de falta de comunicación**